# Set $PS1 differently on local computer and in ssh session

Tags: bash, ssh, shell, ps1

I keep my home directory under version control, so that my basic configuration is easily available on any computer.

My bash command prompt on my local computer is a complicated, colorful thing that includes the current git repository and its state.  But I'd rather have a simple `user@host ~ $` command prompt when I `ssh` into a remote machine.

I'd like to be able to update my `.profile` so that it sets up a complicated `$PS1` when running locally and a simplified one when running in an `ssh` session.

Basically, I'd like something like an `$AM_I_LOGGED_IN_VIA_SSH` variable to test in my `.profile`.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you login via SSH, several extra environment variables get set. You could use these as a test to set your PS1 in your .profile.

```
if [ -n "$SSH_CLIENT" ]; then
    PS1="Via ssh: "
else
    PS1="Local: "
fi
```

Answer (score 7):

If you check your environment (`env | grep SSH`) you'll find several candidates such as `$SSH_CLIENT`, `$SSH_CONNECTION`, and `$SSH_TTY`; the exact list will depend on the `sshd` version.

Answer (score 2):

If your sshd is not providing useful variables, you could use

`ps -p $PPID`

or some other random ps trick (if your shell doesn't set `$PPID`) to see if the shell's parent process is your remote-login-process or not.  Then if parent-is-remote-thingie switch $PS1.  And then download OpenSSH and use geekosaur/Caleb's suggestions because your ssh server is junk. ;)

Or, you can use the output of "who am i", grab the last field (ie, `$( who am i | awk '$0=$NF')` ), and check to see if the host is a remote one or local to decide if you logged in locally or remotely.

Or you can switch on the output of `$(hostname)` to have your shell use the appropriate $PS1 on specific hosts.

Or, let's really go nuts.
If you're using a modern shell - like bash, ksh93, or zsh, you can take advantage of the fact that $PS1 is reevaluated upon execution.  So, you could include an inline conditional block to do the crazy git stuff if your cwd is within the repository, and something else outside.  For example, here I'm making my prompt change depending on the directory I'm in by using `[[ conditional ]] && $( echo "whatever it should be if true) || $( echo "whatever should be the if-not-true prompt" )`, basically.

```
default prompt$ PS1='$(id -un) @ $(hostname)$( [[ $(pwd) = /tmp ]] && echo " [I am in /tmp]" || echo " /not/in/tmp")$ '
myname @ host /not/in/tmp$ cd /tmp
myname @ host [I am in /tmp]$ cd /etc
myname @ host /not/in/tmp$
```

Sure, the $PS1 definition will look crazy in your profile, but you then only get super-colorful-git-stuff when you're actually in the git repository, while you ahve regular colors elsewhere. :)  Note that you have to use single quotes around the PS1 assignment.  You do not want the variables expanded when PS1 is assigned; you want them expanded when $PS1 is evaluated later.  So, single-quotes.

Answer (score 1):

If `PermitUserEnvironment` is enabled in sshd then you can use `~/.ssh/environment` to create `$PS1` and then just detect presence of a value in your script that normally sets it.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to Ignacio's answer, to make things clear, `PermitUSerEnvironment` option must be enabled on server side for this to work.
If server doesn't enable this option, you won't have colorful ssh session with that server.